# How can I, using django, successfully send json data to a postgres database after receiving this data from an API call?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am fairly new to django, I have recently built an app that makes API calls.

home -> this view asks user for the url. User gives url and clicks submit, on submit sends this url to new view and handles call in "request"

request -> receives url, process' call and brings back json data and prints data on screen.

As of now this data just gets printed but is not saved in any way.

During the printing of the data I need it to send the data to a postgres db so I can refer to it later. The table is built and is connected to django framework and can accept data.

this is the code that built the table in postgres db

```
from django.db import models


class URLData(models.Model):
    id          = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    title       = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    summary     = models.TextField()
    description = models.TextField()
    url         = models.URLField(max_length=200)
    rssFeed     = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    links       = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

What functions or commands, using python and django's framework can make this successful? I know this is a very broad statement I am new to using stackoverflow and do not know what is required of me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please show the code for statement "The table is built and is connected to Django framework and can accept data.". This should be a Django Model, please edit your question to include the Model you speak of.

Comment: @ErionV I have updated the question to show the code for the Django Model

Comment: Have you gone through or read the Django tutorial?

Comment: Can you please provide an example of the JSON response you are receiving from the third party API. The more information we have the easier it is for us to help you.